# How to configure properties of sqs in java lambda function?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, polling

I have to create java Lambda function for polling sms event from aws sqs every second.
I got below code from AWS docs article for handler.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-create-package.html

But I am not seeing sqs detail like url configuration any where in this code.

Where to configure sqs uri and polling time properties in java program of lambda function?

Comment: [Please read this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask on StackOverflow... this is mostly programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure a *Lambda Trigger* in SQS, so that SQS knows which Lambda to trigger, when it has new items to deliver. This is nothing you configure at your Lambda or it's code. All of the relevant configuration is done in SQS.

To find out how to configure a Lambda Trigger, please read the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html